# Can ERC 20 Token Name clash

Tags: solidity, etherscan

Created a Contact and got it verified on Etherscan.com with name, symbol etc.
Now again I create another ERC20 contact with the same Name and same symbol but with **another contact address** will it not cause a confusion to people who will use my previous Token.

Comment: Why  would it create confusion until they buy the token from you ? If you feel that you want to change your token name in future,then you would have a set function in contract  which would change the token name.

Comment: Someone could create same name token and symbol and impersonate by selling the token, cannot it happen?? That's why there is a verification process of token in ethereum blockchain..isn't it?

Comment: when you say selling the token ?  There should be an address from which you buy tokens ? Is the address not good enough to identify between you and fake one ?

Comment: Yah..of course the address will different that is not issue.. what i am worried is people can get sometime spoofed by tricks.... Anyways thanks for response.

Comment: Spoofing is common irrespective of platform. It's generally upto the owner to create awareness  of attacks to end user. As long as ethereum is concerned, the only way to pay is via address and you can leave a custom message to end user to double check address you pay.